# Ajax request won't work when I do a select on database. (Laravel)

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

The code above is my controller.

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class AjaxController extends Controller
    {
        public function post(Request $request){
          session_start();
          $select=DB::select('select empresa from users where username = su');

          $response = array(
              'status' => 'success',
              'msg' => $request->message,
          );
          return response()->json($response);

       }
    }
```

In my view I have only an input and a function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
            $(".postbutton").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    /* the route pointing to the post function */
                    url: '/postajax',
                    type: 'POST',
                    /* send the csrf-token and the input to the controller */
                    data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, message:$(".getinfo").val()},
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    /* remind that 'data' is the response of the AjaxController */
                    success: function (data) { 
                        $(".writeinfo").append(data.msg); 
                    }
                }); 
            });
       });    

<body>
    <input class="getinfo"></input>
    <button class="postbutton">Post via Ajax!</button>
    <div class="writeinfo"></div>   
</body>
```

When I I try to do a select to the database the ajax request don't work. If the ajax request worked I would use $select instead of $request.

Comment: Can we see logs from dev tools? Or what you get from the server?  This way we can't help.

Comment: @MilosKovacevic https://i.imgur.com/5HjrEXi.png

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `username = su`, but it's trying to compare the username column to the su column. Do both exist?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Are there any errors on server?

Comment: @aynber Yes the error was on the mysql code.. Appreciated your help guys.

Comment: any reason you are calling `session_start()` in your controller? Laravel has its own session handler that does not use PHPs system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add quotes to value of username:

```
$select=DB::select("select empresa from users where username = 'su'");
```